# Applying a Subroutine to a Range of Dates in Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have the following subroutine coded in Access VBA:

```
  Sub SampleReadCurve()

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim iRow As Long, iField As Long
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim CurveID As Long
    Dim MarkRunID As Long
    Dim ZeroCurveID As String

    CurveID = 124
    MarkRunID = 10167
    ZeroCurveID = "'" & CurveID & "-" & MarkRunID & "'"

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE ZeroCurveID=" & ZeroCurveID & " ORDER BY MaturityDate"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)

    If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Debug.Print vbCrLf
        Debug.Print "First", rs.Fields("ZeroCurveID"), rs.Fields("MaturityDate"), rs.Fields("ZeroRate"), rs.Fields("DiscountFactor")
        rs.MoveLast
        Debug.Print "Last", rs.Fields("ZeroCurveID"), rs.Fields("MaturityDate"), rs.Fields("ZeroRate"), rs.Fields("DiscountFactor")
        Debug.Print "There are " & rs.RecordCount & " records and " & rs.Fields.Count & " fields."

        Dim BucketTermAmt As Long
        Dim BucketTermUnit As String
        Dim BucketDate As Date
        Dim MarkAsOfDate As Date
        Dim InterpRate As Double

        MarkAsOfDate = #7/31/2015#

        BucketTermAmt = 3
        BucketTermUnit = "m"
        BucketDate = DateAdd(BucketTermUnit, BucketTermAmt, MarkAsOfDate)
        InterpRate = CurveInterpolateRecordset(rs, BucketDate)
        Debug.Print BucketDate, InterpRate
    End If


End Sub
```

As it's written right now, this subroutine applies to the MarkAsOfDate value specified, which is #7/31/2015#. Right now, this date is hard coded.

However, I want to change this function so that it will do the same procedure for the last 76 dates, instead of just the one hard coded date. So instead of just applying to MarkAsOfDate = #7/31/2015#, I want to automatically run it for 7/30/2015, 7/29/2015, 7/28/2015 etc for 76 dates previous to the one specified. Right now, the only way I can do this is by manually changing the MarkAsofDate line and running it 76 separate times for each date.

How can I change this function so that it will apply to a specified MarkAsOfDate and 76 dates previous to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly try the following code.

```
Sub SampleReadCurve()

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim iRow As Long, iField As Long
Dim strSQL As String
Dim CurveID As Long
Dim MarkRunID As Long
Dim ZeroCurveID As String

CurveID = 124
MarkRunID = 10167
ZeroCurveID = "'" & CurveID & "-" & MarkRunID & "'"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE ZeroCurveID=" & ZeroCurveID & " ORDER BY MaturityDate"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)

If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Debug.Print vbCrLf
    Debug.Print "First", rs.Fields("ZeroCurveID"), rs.Fields("MaturityDate"), rs.Fields("ZeroRate"), rs.Fields("DiscountFactor")
    rs.MoveLast
    Debug.Print "Last", rs.Fields("ZeroCurveID"), rs.Fields("MaturityDate"), rs.Fields("ZeroRate"), rs.Fields("DiscountFactor")
    Debug.Print "There are " & rs.RecordCount & " records and " & rs.Fields.Count & " fields."

    Dim BucketTermAmt As Long
    Dim BucketTermUnit As String
    Dim BucketDate As Date
    Dim MarkAsOfDate As Date
    Dim InterpRate As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim userdate As String


    userdate = InputBox("Enter Date in as per your system date format eg 31/07/2015 in the system date is in dd/mm/yyyy format")

For i = -75 To 0

    MarkAsOfDate = DateAdd("d", i, userdate)
    BucketTermAmt = 3
    BucketTermUnit = "m"
    BucketDate = DateAdd(BucketTermUnit, BucketTermAmt, MarkAsOfDate)
    InterpRate = CurveInterpolateRecordset(rs, BucketDate)
    Debug.Print BucketDate, InterpRate
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `For ... Next` loop to your code:

```
Sub SampleReadCurve()

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim iRow As Long, iField As Long
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim CurveID As Long
    Dim MarkRunID As Long
    Dim ZeroCurveID As String

    CurveID = 124
    MarkRunID = 10167
    ZeroCurveID = "'" & CurveID & "-" & MarkRunID & "'"

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VolatilityOutput WHERE ZeroCurveID=" & ZeroCurveID & " ORDER BY MaturityDate"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)

    If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Debug.Print vbCrLf
        Debug.Print "First", rs.Fields("ZeroCurveID"), rs.Fields("MaturityDate"), rs.Fields("ZeroRate"), rs.Fields("DiscountFactor")
        rs.MoveLast
        Debug.Print "Last", rs.Fields("ZeroCurveID"), rs.Fields("MaturityDate"), rs.Fields("ZeroRate"), rs.Fields("DiscountFactor")
        Debug.Print "There are " & rs.RecordCount & " records and " & rs.Fields.Count & " fields."

        Dim BucketTermAmt As Long
        Dim BucketTermUnit As String
        Dim BucketDate As Date
        Dim MarkAsOfDate As Date
        Dim InterpRate As Double
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim d As Date

        MarkAsOfDate = #7/31/2015#

        For i = 0 To 76
            d = VBA.DateAdd("d", -i, MarkAsOfDate)
            BucketTermAmt = 3
            BucketTermUnit = "m"
            BucketDate = DateAdd(BucketTermUnit, BucketTermAmt, d)
            InterpRate = CurveInterpolateRecordset(rs, BucketDate)
            Debug.Print BucketDate, InterpRate
        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```